# Serializing saves only the last entered value GUI tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am serializing my GUI to save the information.But the problem is that it is only saving the last value entered not all of them.
So now the problem is that when I click on the **+** button, the row gets incremented but only the last name entered is saved. I want to save all of them

```
def increment(self):
    current_row=1
    MoreButton=Button(self.listFrame,text="+",command=entry_1(self))
    MoreButton.grid(column=1,row=0)
def entry_1(self):
    self.entryName=Entry(self.listFrame)
    self.entryName.grid(column=1,row=current_row,sticky="EW")
    self.entryName.get()
    nameLabel=Label(self.listFrame,text="NAME")
    nameLabel.grid(column=0,row=current_row)
    save_button=Button(self.listFrame,text="save",command=save_data(self))
    save_button.grid(column=2,row=0)
    current_row=current_row+1

def save_data(self):
    data={
        "Name":self.entryName.get(),
        }
    with open("test.json","wb") as f:
        dill.dump(data,f)

def load_data(self):
    with open("test.json","rb") as f:
        data=dill.load(f)
```

Comment: What are you using to sterilise the data?

Comment: And can I please have a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) answer.

Comment: Keep all names on list (not only in Entry) and save all list.

Comment: @furas Will you please give me an example. I didnt get it

Comment: Very sorry @user5517005, I made a mistake in my answer. The problem is that when you create the new entry boxes, they all have the same name. I am trying to work out a solution to this.

Comment: @JonahFleming Can you just give me one example or like one hint

Comment: I'm working in it and I will have it by this evening. Sorry.

Comment: Its completely fine @JonahFleming Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the past incorrect answer. I think the problem is that your `entry_1` function creates entry boxes with the same name. This means when you try getting the text in it, it gets the text of the last one only. Here is the full code I created that creates entry's with different names. It is in a class but I don't know how you want them set out.

```
from Tkinter import *
import dill
import sys
boxes=[]
no_of_boxes=0
root=Tk()
current_row=1
current_box=0
data={}

class Main(object):
#this is used every time a new entry is created
    def save_data(self):
        global current_box
        global current_row
        global no_of_boxes
        ###this it the key. It creates the entries
        ###in a list so that we can access them
        ###without the name
        boxes.append(Entry(root))
        boxes[-1].grid(column=1, row=current_row)
        ###
        try:
            data["Name"+str(current_box)]=boxes[-2].get()
        except:
            data["Name"+str(current_box)]=boxes[-1].get()
        current_row+=1
        current_box+=1
        no_of_boxes+=1
        print no_of_boxes
        print boxes
        print data
        with open("test.json","wb") as f:
            dill.dump(data,f)
    #to save when closing
    def save_close(self):
        global current_box
        global current_row
        boxes.append(Entry(root))
        boxes[-1].grid(column=1, row=current_row)
        data["Name"+str(current_box)]=boxes[-2].get()
        with open("test.json","wb") as f:
            dill.dump(data,f)
        print no_of_boxes
        print boxes
        print data
        sys.exit()


    def load_data(self):
        with open("test.json","rb") as f:
            data=dill.load(f)

    def entry_1(self):
        global current_row
        global no_of_boxes
        nameLabel=Label(root,text="NAME")
        nameLabel.grid(column=0,row=current_row)
        self.save_data()

app=Main()
MoreButton=Button(root,text="+",command=app.entry_1)
MoreButton.grid(column=1,row=0)
CloseButton=Button(root, text="Close and save", command=app.save_close)
CloseButton.grid(column=2, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

The saved data is saved as `"Name"` plus `current_box` in `data` so to get it go `data["Name1"]` for entry box 1 and so on.
I hope this is a better answer than my last one!

P.S if you still have problems with other parts of this code, feel free to contact me on my [website](https://pythonqanda.weebly.com/).